# how to count words upto a limit in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code, to count the frequency of word occurrences in a document containing about 20,000 files,i am able to get the overall frequency of a word in the document and
my code so far is:

```
import os
import re
import sys
sys.stdout=open('f2.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob

def removegarbage(text):
    text=re.sub(r'\W+',' ',text)
    text=text.lower()
    return text

folderpath='d:/articles-words'
counter=Counter()
d=0

for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')):
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        d+=1

r=round(d*0.1)
for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')):
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        words=set(removegarbage(filehandle.read()).split())
        if r > counter:
             counter.update()

for word,count in counter.most_common():
    print('{}  {}'.format(word,count))
```

But, I want to modify my counter, and update it only when the count is greater than r=0.1*(no of files)
in short, i want to read words whose frequency in the entire document is greater than 10% of the number of documents.
the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > Counter()
```

how do I modify it?

Comment: What do you expect `if r > counter: counter.update()` to do?

Comment: i want the counter to update only if it satisfies the condition

Comment: Read about what `.update()` actually does: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update

Comment: What do you mean by `when the count is greater than r=0.1*(no of files)`? What count?

Comment: it must count values till it  is greater than the value of r,and here the value of r is o.1*number of files

Comment: So you only want to count words that occur more than a certain number of times?  When you see the first occurrence of `zebra` how are you going to know whether it will ultimately turn out to occur frequently or not, if you don't count it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about somethiing like this?

```
from glob import glob # (instead of iglob)

...

filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

num_files = len(filepaths)

# Add all words to counter
for filepath in filepaths):
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        lines = filehandle.read()
        words = removegarbage(lines).split()
        counter.update(words)

# Display most common
for word, count in counter.most_common():

    # Break out if the frequency is less than 0.1 * the number of files
    if count < 0.1*num_files:
        break

    print('{}  {}'.format(word,count))
```

---

Use of `Counter.iteritems()`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c.update(['test', 'test', 'test2'])
>>> c.iteritems()
<dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x012F4750>
>>> for word, count in c.iteritems():
...     print word, count
...     
test 2
test2 1
```

Comment: The `read` method of a file returns a single sting, not a sequence of lines. Do you mean `readlines`?

Comment: i want to read only  those words,whose frequency count in the entire document is greater than 10% of the number of documents

Comment: @PokerFace How's something like this?

Comment: Rather than popping the words with too few occurrences out of the counter, you could simply `break` out of output loop when the count gets lower than the desired amount. Since the iteration is from most common to least common, this will exclude all the low counts.

Comment: @Blckknght Good point - I was assuming that the OP would go on to use counter for something else after printing it. I also wonder if the most_common() call might be slower than popping - depends on his use case

Comment: @AlexL the line: num_files = len(filepaths), doesn't work! TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: @PokerFace Don't forget I changed  `iglob` to `glob`, which should work because glob returns a list.

Comment: well in that case,filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')) doesn't work!TypeError: 'module' object is not callable,Plz help!!

Comment: @PokerFace Make sure you're doing `from glob import glob` not `import glob`

Comment: @AlexL: what does iteritems do here?it says Attribute :Counter object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @PokerFace I've updated my answer to demonstrate how it works (for me, on Python 2.7)

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error, i am working on Python 3.3, is there any other substitute for iteritems??

Comment: @PokerFace Use `.items()` in Python 3.3. http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: it shows a RuntimeError:dictionary changed size during iteration,plz help!!

Comment: Ah, oops. You're not supposed to remove keys from a dictionary while you're iterating. I suggest you try Blckknght's approach - break from the loop when printing. (Updated ans)